# how do i store the object reference after the element created in raphael js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael, graphael

I am drawing SVG lines using Raphael JS. And adding id to those lines using **node.id = "lines"**. By doing this I am creating id for the lines I created.
My problem is I am creating multiple lines. If it is one line then I can use the **$('#lines').attr("data"," ")** something. Because of Multiple line if use this method all elements data will be changed. 
 After the **variable.node.id** how do I access that particular element and store some data in it. 
I am new to Raphael JS. Tell me if anything can replace the node.id method also.

Thanks 
[image]

This is how my function looks

Comment: All id values must be unique. It's not clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes I know but it is not allowing me to create class

Comment: l.node.setAttribute("class', "whatever your class name is");

Comment: http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Paper.getById you can use getById if you want, just make sure you created one that's unique as mentioned by Robert. It's not very clear as mentioned what you are trying to achieve though